# how to find index of last ")" in R

Tags: r

I have a R character string.

```
 a<- c("hi this is ( learning) R (analytics) and")
```

I want to get index of last ")" bracket. Above string pattern can be of any type. I was trying something like this :

```
     sapply(gregexpr("\\)", a), '[', 1)
```

But, above statement is returning the index value of first "(". Also not sure if this is efficient way as well or not.

Comment: Use `tail, 1` instead of `\`[\`, 1` As to the efficiency, I do not know.

Comment: `tail(gregexpr("\\)", a)[[1]],1)` would probably be more efficient

Comment: @AndrewGustar - if you're only looking in one string, then efficiency is not going to be a big concern. I was assuming `a` might be longer than one string.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `stringi` package and its `stri_locate_last_*` functions. Since here we are not looking for a `regex`, but for a fixed pattern, we use `stri_locate_last_fixed`:

```
require(stringi)
stri_locate_last_fixed(a,")")
#     start end
#[1,]    36  36
```

The above is fully vectorized and C implemented, so `a` can have a >1 lenght and it's likely very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` methods

```
nchar(sub("[)][^)]*$", "", a))+1
#[1] 36
```

Or with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
tail(str_locate_all(a, "[)]")[[1]],1)
#     start end
#[2,]    36  36
```